# Selenium sendKeys send partial value

Tags: python, selenium

This is pretty much all the code

```
code = '123456789123456798abcdefghilmnopqrstuvz...' # very long code (~60 chars)

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://localhost/mytest")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

text = re.search('lorem ipsum \s\((.+?)\)', driver.page_source) # extract text between parentheses from the whole page

ActionChains(driver)\
        .send_keys(Keys.TAB)\
        .send_keys(code)\
        .send_keys(Keys.TAB)\
        .send_keys(text.group(1))\
        .send_keys(Keys.TAB)\
        .send_keys(Keys.SPACE)\
        .perform()
```

Even if the string `code` is very long it looks `send_keys` always works fine.
Usually  `text.group(1)` is a 4-5 char long string, but `send_keys` randomly seems to lost some chars.

Comment: right, what is the question ?

Comment: it sounds like you're sending the keys to a text field. does the text filed have a character input limit?

Comment: @crookedleaf yep after 15 minute wasted on Selenium docs, indeed the answer was that easy :)